# Align image and text on textview

Tags: android, textview, imageview, android-linearlayout

In my app, I populate a linearlayout with a text and a little icon (like a listview with a custom adapter). 
I need the text and the picture to have the same size. Is there a way to do that?

Here's the code:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
              LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      LinearLayout LayoutPadre = new LinearLayout(this);
TextView Tag = new TextView(this);
      ImageView img = new ImageView(this);

      Tag.setText(data);
     if(stato.equalsIgnoreCase("presente")){
      img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_presente); 
     }else{
         img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_assente);  
     }

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(75, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);   //Here I need the img to have same size as the text, but Tag.getHeight() returns 0
      layoutParams.setMargins(50, 0, 0, 0);

      img.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

      LayoutPadre.setLayoutParams(params);

      LayoutPadre.addView(Tag);
      LayoutPadre.addView(img);
```

The problem is that the image is not horizontally centered like the img.
Look at the screen[image: Sreen capture]

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep the layout_height of text and image as `Match_Parent` and not `Wrap_Content`... By that

Comment: thank's! it work!! i mak ea lot of attempt, but not thant..Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you are preserving the `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` or it did not work, you can also do `android:gravity="center"`