# How to use the Image(Stored Image of device) with Text on TextView Android?

Tags: java, android, image, imagespan

I am creating the chat app , in which i am getting the **EMOJI** from the server (IMAGE URLS).

I am using this images(Emoji url) with text in my `TextView` by below lines of the code.

```
String stringWithHtml = "Sample string with an <img src=\"http://MY_SERVER.emoji.s3.amazonaws.com/cf68/5794d5f7895fa10a8f8e1350/imgList/5794d5f7895fa10a8f8e136a.png\"></img>" +
                        "<img src=\"http://MY_SERVER.emoji.s3.amazonaws.com/cf68/5794d5f7895fa10a8f8e1350/imgList/5794d5f7895fa10a8f8e135a.png\"></img>"+
                        "<img src=\"http://MY_SERVER.emoji.s3.amazonaws.com/cf68/5794d5f7895fa10a8f8e1350/imgList/5794d5f7895fa10a8f8e135b.png\"></img>"; 


Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(new URL(source).openStream(), "src name");
                    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

Spanned spannedValue = Html.fromHtml(stringWithHtml, drawable, null); 
MY_TEXTVIEW.setText(spannedValue);
```

This all stuff , i am using in the `AsynTask` and getting the expected result like below:-

[image: My Result]

Now i am storing all the emojis(Images) on my device and want to use it with text in my `TextView`.

> **My question is that How can we use the device(Stored images) with text on my TextView ?**

I have searched about it on SO but did not get the expected result.Please check below link which i have visited.

[1. First Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352496/how-to-add-image-in-a-textview-text) 
[2. Second Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953379/android-add-image-to-text-in-text-view) 
[3. Third Link](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/introduction-to-spans/)  
[4. Forth Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390096/align-image-and-text-on-textview)

I have used the `ImageSpan`for it but the other problem arises , which i have posted the question on **SO** [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674410/getting-exceptionbitmapfactory-unable-to-decode-stream-android-while-using)

Please help me to short out from this problem.Thanks

Comment: Hi Ravindra Kushwaha,you can check my answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859800/is-there-any-way-to-insert-an-imagespan-in-a-textview-without-disrupting-the-tex

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16769333/2398375)? Your previous post about `ImageSpan` is *horribly* formatted - it doesn't even express any use of `ImageSpan`, so it was probably ignored by many.

Comment: @VinceEmigh please check my link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674410/getting-exceptionbitmapfactory-unable-to-decode-stream-android-while-using

Answer (score 8):

OK. You even no need Uri. try this:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/car_icon.png";

                String stringWithHtml = "Sample string with an <img src=" + path + "></img>"
                +" <img src=" + path + "></img>"
                +" <img src=" + path + "></img>";

                Html.ImageGetter getter = new Html.ImageGetter() {
                    @Override
                    public Drawable getDrawable(String s) {
                        return BitmapDrawable.createFromPath(s);
                    }
                };               

                Spanned spannedValue = Html.fromHtml(stringWithHtml, getter, null);
                text.setText(spannedValue);'
```

Comment: Can u please add some more code on it..I did not get urs solution

Comment: I Edited my answer

Comment: Ok i will let you know soon

Comment: I have tried urs solution and it did not work..Please check my code , which i have done according to u https://ibb.co/caDk75

Comment: Try the solution from link I attached. The solution from link works 100 %

Comment: In the link , they have not used the device image, please check it once..

Comment: There is no other way

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a java program to get the count of the emoji's you receive.

And Dynamically create ImageView component in the UIView using the below program. Please use looping structures to repeat as much as you need.

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView();
RelativeLayout parentView = findViewById("R.id.parentViewId");
parentView.addView(iv, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for loading images in textview from servers as well as from sdcard.. you can use sdcard related code :)

```
Spanned spanned = null;
String messageCustomized = "<img src ='"+ imageFileName +"'/>";
Spanned span = Html.fromHtml(messageCustomized, new 
URLImageParser(sentMessagesViewHolder.tvMessage, context), null);
if (spanned!=null) {
      spanned = (Spanned) TextUtils.concat(spanned, span);
}else spanned= span;

if (spanned!=null) {
   txtView.setText(spanned);
 }
```

### ImageGetter

```
public class URLImageParser implements ImageGetter {
Context context;
View container;
private int imageSize = 20;
private int imageSizeDisplaySize = 20;
URLDrawable urlDrawable = null;

public URLImageParser(View container, Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.container = container;
    imageSize = Utility.convertDpTopPixels(context, 20);
    imageSizeDisplaySize = Utility.convertDpTopPixels(context, 35);

}

@Override
public Drawable getDrawable(final String fileName) {


    urlDrawable = new URLDrawable();
    Drawable drawable = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
        drawable = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.profile_main_placeholder);
    else
        drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile_main_placeholder);

    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + imageSize, 0 + imageSize);
    urlDrawable.drawable = drawable;

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    bitmap = ImageUtility.getImageFromSDCard(fileName);
    if (bitmap != null) {   // the bitmap is available

        bitmap = RoundedImageView.getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, imageSize, imageSize, imageSize);
        drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);//ImageUtility.bitmapToDrawable(context,resource);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + imageSize, 0 + imageSize); //set the correct bound according to the result from HTTP call
        URLImageParser.this.urlDrawable.drawable = drawable;

    }
    return urlDrawable.drawable; 

}
}
```

### URLDrawable

```
public class URLDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
   protected Drawable drawable;

   @Override
   public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    // override the draw to facilitate refresh function later
       if(drawable != null) {
           drawable.draw(canvas);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: i do not want to use the `url` like in your code `WebConstant.IMAGE_BASE_URL` ..I have stored image on my sd card. i need to use this images of sd card with my text..Please help me on it

Comment: kindly look at the code it checks if image is available in the sdcard then load from there..

Comment: Have a look at URLImageParser

Comment: Bro please check this line ` drawable = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.profile_main_placeholder); ` , it is using the  app images..I have image on my sd card which i want to use these with text..Please check ur code once..Thanks

Comment: bitmap = ImageUtility.getImageFromSDCard(fileName);


 if (bitmap != null) {   // the bitmap is available

        bitmap = RoundedImageView.getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, imageSize, imageSize, imageSize);
        drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);//ImageUtility.bitmapToDrawable(context,resource);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + imageSize, 0 + imageSize); //set the correct bound according to the result from HTTP call
        URLImageParser.this.urlDrawable.drawable = drawable;

Comment: could u please add it on the your solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152998/discussion-between-naveed-ali-and-ravindra-kushwaha).

Comment: did you get it?

Comment: for your effort +1 from my side...Plz give me time , i am on the others task..Will let u know tomorrow

Comment: Ok I have updated code.. now it will be easy for you

Comment: please help me..What is `URLDrawable` , as i copied urs code ..It is not recognizing the `URLDrawable`..PLease check the image https://ibb.co/jiM6u5

Comment: Can u please help me on the URL images ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [emojicon](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon) library , also refer [here](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojiconize) , sample source code included.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:emojicon="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <io.github.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtEmojicon"
            android:text="I \ue32d emojicon"
            emojicon:emojiconAlignment="baseline"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <io.github.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText
            android:id="@+id/editEmojicon"
            android:text="I \ue32d emojicon"
            emojicon:emojiconSize="28sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/emojicons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            class="io.github.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconsFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

you can add custom emojis like below

```
 EmojiconsView emojiconsView = (EmojiconsView) findViewById(R.id.emojicons_view);
        emojiconsView.setPages(Arrays.asList(
                new EmojiconPage(Emojicon.TYPE_PEOPLE, null, false, R.drawable.ic_emoji_people_light),
                new EmojiconPage(Emojicon.TYPE_NATURE, null, false, R.drawable.ic_emoji_nature_light),
                new EmojiconPage(Emojicon.TYPE_OBJECTS, null, false, R.drawable.ic_emoji_objects_light),
                new EmojiconPage(Emojicon.TYPE_PLACES, null, false, R.drawable.ic_emoji_places_light),
                new EmojiconPage(Emojicon.TYPE_SYMBOLS, null, false, R.drawable.ic_emoji_symbols_light)
        ));
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not using any EMOJI..As i have mentioned in the question that i need IMAGE with TEXT on TEXTVIEW..IMAGES are saved on the my devices..I need to use the image with text

Comment: Link which u have shared is the Emoji with text .Not for text with image